# Typescript return type is not fully respected and can include unknown keys

Tags: typescript

Here are my types:

```
interface Classroom<T> {
    someAction: (cb: ActionCb<T>) => void;
}

type ActionCb<T> = (state: T) => T;

type User = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Now say I create an instance of classroom somehow:

```
const classRoom: Classroom<User> = ...
```

And invoking the `someAction` is now not behaving the way I expect:

```
// No warning, and this is correct
classRoom.someAction((state) => {
    return {
        ...state
    };
});

// No warning, and this is correct
classRoom.someAction((state) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        age: 123
    };
});

// Warning, but this is also correct warning
classRoom.someAction((state) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        age: 'sdf'
    };
});

// Now this fails
// The property `foo` is incorrect; but there is no warning
classRoom.someAction((state) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        foo: 123
    };
});

// But then this fixes it, but it is redundant
classRoom.someAction((state): User => {
    return {
        ...state,
        foo: 123
    };
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about: `return { ...state, foo: 123 } as User`? The `as User` syntax should throw you errors / warnings, otherwise typescript interpretes it as a regular object and may not give warning or hints (using tslint, though, it should warn you).

Comment: @briosheje yes that would work. But why do I need to explicitly say that? The interface of the `Classroom` should already check for that. That is redundant in my opinino.

Comment: type checking is misleading (sometimes). I've been writing an entire library in typescript and, using tslint, the above code (the one with foo) won't only give a warning, but **won't even allow me to compile**. In any case, as far as I remember, the `as {something}` syntax is somehow necessary, since the warning only fires on **object literals** (and the spread operator will break the check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning about extra properties only fires for object literals.

```
// warning, object literals may only specify known properties
const x: {y: number} = {y: 42, z: 30};
```

Objects with object spread do not have this warning. Having said that, extra properties really do not matter from a typing perspective, all the required properties are still there.

If you feel strongly about it, have the `someAction` callback not know about `state` and don't use it to merge with the properties you give, but do it on a different layer.

Comment: Is there a reason for this limitation? Shouldn't extra properties actually do count?  I don't agree with `extra properties really do not matter from a typing perspective`.

Comment: Why would they? You asked for a `name: string` and `age: number`, as long as the object you asked for has both of those properties, why do you care what else it has? Interfaces are minimal by design, you ask for what you need, and ignore the extra.