# Is there an option to make spreading an object strict?

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if there is a compiler option or something similar to make spreading objects strict.

Please see following example to understand what I mean:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
}

interface Bar {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

const barObject: Bar = { a: "a string", b: 1 };

// should give a warning because Bar has more properties (here b) than Foo
const fooObject: Foo = { ...barObject };

// actually prints 1
console.log((fooObject as any).b);
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Hmm, seems a bit inconsistent, since `const fooObject: Foo = {a: "hello"}; fooObject.b = 1;` *does* throw a compiler error, however spreading doesn't.

Comment: Ya, in fact so does `const foo: Foo = { ...bar, b: 2 }` would complain. No idea why.

Comment: Also `const foo: Foo = Object.assign({}, { ...barObject }, {somethingElse: true})`  does not complain...

Comment: @Kousha moreover, the compiler *knows* the structure of `barObject`, as it correctly marks the spreading as safe, because the `a` property matches. If you do `const fooObject: Foo = { ...({x: 1, y: 2}) };` then it throws an error because there is no `a` property. It just never flags the extra properties in these cases.

Comment: OK, found some more questiosn abut this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788052/using-spread-operator-in-typescript/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525777/typescript-type-not-working-with-spread-operator/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789057/typescript-return-type-is-not-fully-respected-and-can-include-unknown-keys/ basically, it seems like it's a long standing thing. Either live with it (after all, you the compiler will stop you from using `fooObject.b`) or write some helper function that only picks relevant properties to assign.

Comment: @VLAZ `fooObject.b` fails and `(fooObject as any).b` works *either way*, that's not inconsistent; having extra properties isn't a problem, accessing them through the wrong interface is.

Comment: @Kousha because that's an extra *literal* prop, think of it like runtime vs compile time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's still not okay; imagine I do a spread and then do POST that object to service; it will end up sending all of those extra parameters that I may not want to send.

Comment: @Kousha something similar actually happened to me (while mapping frontend to backend models), which is why I'm asking this question. It's kind of cumbersome to find such an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting question. According to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19775), the result of the spread operator is intended to *not* trigger [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).

```
// barObject has more props than Foo, but spread does not trigger excess property checks
const fooObject: Foo = { ...barObject };

// b is explicit property, so checks kicks in here
const foo: Foo = { ...bar, b: 2 }
```

There aren't [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) for TypeScript currently, but you can create a simple type check to enforce strict object spread:

```
// returns T, if T and U match, else never
type ExactType<T, U> = T extends U ? U extends T ? T : never : never

const bar: Bar = { a: "a string", b: 1 };
const foo: Foo = { a: "foofoo" }

const fooMergeError: Foo = { ...bar as ExactType<typeof bar, Foo> }; // error
const fooMergeOK: Foo = { ...foo as ExactType<typeof foo, Foo> }; // OK
```

With a helper function, we can reduce redundancy a bit:

```
const enforceExactType = <E>() => <T>(t: ExactType<T, E>) => t

const fooMergeError2: Foo = { ...enforceExactType<Foo>()(bar) }; // error
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRycAXMgM5hSgDmA3AQL4EGiSyIoBCcUOBYiXJUaIBoOIAjciACuAWynRG+FvgIB6TcigQwcqCArIAKgBpkwGGZIgAJsgCqyCAA9EYSxAA2FFCAQAG7QBGAAngAOKACiHghgplEQADwWzgB8yAC8tu6QDiYuAPzOrm4F9iamyKU1ssHQyA0hUKz4COjGYMhSfOS8-LnYwsgARHCU1HRjljLIAIzITKqd3cgwmOQYWMOjY5voh2PL7WtUG5gAstC0EDFQUOhQ25g5OMgAdN99-HAmcU8SWiKQi0SOvT4lh2WRWyG0rkezwI5x6hxuUDuAHkANKvXYfb6fQ4kAHxRLJUHJCGHaGYWH0eE6XFnLoXCAgTZQJCAhLAlC5FIxDIACgAlDksmlRWByLyKSD0sKJdksmB2hyuTzyfyUjDxSLsGRxgArf4+ewAaxgYyYEoRAHdnpaKARNc9tUDKfqxYb9maKBbrbNeuQAMzLe06aBPKBzcpICgmSJPSKs9bo273JFQABM+PeIyJ7u59x13vpBt+ErhCJjzyAA)

Comment: so it's not really simple. I would rather have no checks instead of reducing readability of my code. Sad that there is no flag currently..

Comment: In most cases, you probably *want* object spread to add additional properties. It wouldn't make so much sense to disable this feature across-the-board on a project-basis. I think, it would be more useful on a case basis, but here you could also enforce the type of the object before the spread operation (per variable or function parameter type), if you don't like readability of above code. You can also track the exact types issue (no idea, if it gets implemented).

Comment: @ysfaran one addition: object spread currently behaves in accordance with the whole structural type system/duck typing, where a sub type can be assigned to a base type. In a normal variable assignment you only get excess property checks, when you initialize a fresh object literal. For example you can write `const fooObject: Foo = bar`, because `bar` isn't a fresh object literal anymore and a sub type of `Foo`. `const fooObject: Foo = { ...bar }` behaves analogously, `bar` is not "fresh" anymore/ has already been declared before.