# Refer to unknown at advance object key in TypeScript gereric

Tags: typescript

First look, below function `addPropertyIfValueIsNotUndefined` works:

```js
function addPropertyIfValueIsNotUndefined<Value>(key: string, value: Value): { key?: Value; } {
    return isNotUndefined(value) ? { [key]: value } : {};
}

function isNotUndefined<TargetValue>(targetValue: TargetValue | undefined): targetValue is TargetValue {
  return typeof targetValue !== "undefined";
}


type Test = {
    alpha: string;
    bravo?: string; 
}

const test1: Test = { 
    alpha: "ALPHA1" ,
    // bravo: "BRAVO1"
};

const test2: Test = {
    alpha: "ALPHA2",
    ...addPropertyIfValueIsNotUndefined("bravo", test1.bravo)
};

console.log(test2)

// Neither TypeScript compiler nor JavaScript VM errors until here
```

But what if try to add some property that does not declare on type `Test`?
I am expecting that TypeScript emit the error `TS2322 Type { gibberish: string; bravo: string | undefined; alpha: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Test'`, but TypeScript will not emit error or warning!

```js
const test2: Type = {
    alpha: "ALPHA2",
    ...addPropertyIfValueIsNotUndefined("gibberish", test1.bravo)
};
```

Seems like I understood why. But how to annotate the returning value of `addPropertyIfValueIsNotUndefined`? We don't know the key at advance but need refer to it.

[Fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoAoCc4AcCmWUAngJLABqyANiPqQM4BycUAqmKvsDGPqgB4qtfAD4AFAGt8xAFyIGULLwDmAGkQA3GnXnC6ASnkBvRNOIB+PTvwBuRAF9ExgFCJ3iLPiggsSGMysHFw8fKji2iIGiBbOiADa5gC68pF0jogmDrYuDi4uoJCwCIgBLOyc3Lz8AgAqyFgq3vpi4lANTVAt8vWNzTaIAD6I4CHVqEaI7X1dAwGIvZ0tzm6e3r5IJARwwFMd-SKIAIQAvCeIAESjVWEXOXn5W-gL+IqI564eKNS4ABbI8kUyjAKhyXwARlhkJo4FYFEpVPZcvkIAg3lBXlAAIw9THvOKrdw0P4Ay4AQQAMhgABJkrEXRBqQmIAD0LMQkOhcHkFwAQgAlMkUADy9NyORcqLA6MxACZcW8Pszif8eZSaWTZRcmV8AHT6tCYHAEIhkSg2RjlYI3fjiC6cmHaqaYrG6h1wAw6jz63WG7B4QgkcgtS1BSqhW0XFQwcHgwgBX5OjGKV3ugzioA)

Comment: What exatcly you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to copy some property from one object to another? Is it correct that first parameter is a key that should be added to object and the second parameter is value that should be copied? What kind of type check do you expect?

Comment: @НиколайГольцев, I'm sorry about unclear question. "What exatcly you're trying to achieve?" - I want TypeScript emit the error  `TS2322 Type { gibberish: string; bravo: string | undefined; alpha: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Test'`.

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD I got your question now. Sadly it's a known case in typescript.  You can check this so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318739/is-there-an-option-to-make-spreading-an-object-strict) for further info.

Comment: @Eldar, thank you for reading my comments. So the verdict of this question is "No simple way to reach desired effect in TypeScript <=4.1"?

Comment: Yes, and it's a feature of typescript rather than a lack of a feature. And it seems it will stay as-is for a while.

Comment: @Eldar, Got it. Thanks to you, this question is is settled.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified approach which I think accomplishes your goal.  Instead of having a separate function to create the `{key: value}` object, we pass the existing object into the function.

```
function addPropertyIfValueIsNotUndefined<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(
   object: T, key: K, value: Required<T>[K]
): T & Required<Pick<T, K>> {
    return propertyIsNotUndefined(object, key) ? object : { ...object, [key]: value } as T & Required<Pick<T, K>>
}
```

Note that we have to use `as` to return the correct type because of how typescript treats dynamic keys and because it is theoretically possibly for the generic `K` to be wider than just the single key, in which case our return type could be incorrect.

The boolean checker now looks at the property on the object:

```
function propertyIsNotUndefined<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key: K): object is T & Required<Pick<T, K>> {
  return object[key] !== undefined;
}
```

The usage looks like this:

```
const test2 = addPropertyIfValueIsNotUndefined(test1, "bravo", "value") // ok

const test3 = addPropertyIfValueIsNotUndefined(test1, "bravo", undefined) 
// error: Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

const test4 = addPropertyIfValueIsNotUndefined(test1, "wrongKey", "value") 
// error: Argument of type '"wrongKey"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"bravo" | "alpha"'
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoAoCc4AcCmWUAngJLABqyANiPqQM4BycUAqmKvsDGPqgB4qtfAD4AFAGt8xAFyIGULLwDmAGkQA3GnXnC6ASnkBvRNOIB%20PTvwBuRAF9ExgFCJ3iLPiggsSGMysHFw8fKji2iIGiBbOiADa5gC68pF0jogmDrYuDi4uoJCwCIgBLOyc3Lz8AgAqyFgq3vpi4lANTVAt8vWNzTaIAD6I4CHVqEaI7X1dAwGIvZ0tzm6e3r5IJARwwFMd-SKIAIQAvCeIAESjVWEXOXn5W-gL%20IqI564eKNS4ABbI8kUyjAKhyXwARlhkJo4FYFEpVPZcvkIAg3lBXlAAIw9THvOKrdw0P4Ay4AQQAMhgABJkrEXRBqQmIAD0LMQkOhcHkFwAQgAlMkUADy9NyORcqLA6MxACZcW8Pszif8eZSaWTZRcmV8AHT6tCYHAEIhkSg2RjlYI3fjiC6cmHaqaYrG6h1wAw6jz63WG7B4QgkcgtS1BSqhW0XFQwcHgwgBX5OjGKV3ugzioA)