# Spread operator does not error when variable has union type

Tags: typescript, prisma

It's unclear to me why `...options` doesn't error in the call to `this.prisma.store.create` in `StoreService.create` below:

`options` clearly has `shopifyOfflineSession`. The type that I'm passing for that is not valid for `this.prisma.store.create`.

```
export interface BaseCreateStoreOptions {
  // ...
}

export interface StripeCreateStoreOptions extends BaseCreateStoreOptions {
  subscriptionId: string;
  status: StoreStatus;
  customerId: string;
}

export interface ShopifyCreateStoreOptions extends BaseCreateStoreOptions {
  shopifyOfflineSession?: {
    sessionId: string;
    shopId?: bigint;
    accessToken: string;
    isOnline: boolean;
    shop: string;
    state: string;
  };
}


export class StoreService {
  public async create(
    options: StripeCreateStoreOptions | ShopifyCreateStoreOptions,
  ): Promise<CreateStoreType> {
    const store = await this.prisma.store.create({
      include: { accounts: true, shopifyOfflineSession: true },
      data: {
        // No error here:
        ...options,
        
        // This errors, appropriately: 
        // shopifyOfflineSession: {
          // sessionId: '1',
        // },

        // This errors, as it should:
        // shopifyOfflineSession: this.isFromShopify(options)
        // ? options.shopifyOfflineSession
        // : undefined,
      },
    });
  }

  public async somefunc() {
    const store = await this.create({
      // ... 
      shopifyOfflineSession: {
        sessionId: session.id,
        shopId: BigInt(1), // This will update later once we have an accessToken
        state: '',
        isOnline: false,
        accessToken: '1', // This will update later
        shop: session.shop,
      },
      // ...
    }); 
  }
}
```

This has been a gotcha for me and I'd love to avoid it in the future.

Comment: It's because the property is optional, and excess properties are allowed. However, in static object initializers, directly declared properties are disallowed, which is why you are getting this behavior.

Comment: you might want to have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318739/is-there-an-option-to-make-spreading-an-object-strict

Comment: So I guess I'd have to write an eslint rule to prevent spread operator from being using as an arg in prisma?

Comment: The good news is that at least at runtime, Prisma complains about `shopifyOfflineSession` being the wrong type.